# C++ retain lvalueness and rvalueness with local variable

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue-reference

I have a function that takes either a lvalue or rvalue:

```cpp
void doSomething(Foo& foo);
void doSomething(Foo&& foo);
```

And others functions that return either a rvalue or lvalue:

```cpp
Foo fun1();
Foo& fun2();
// ...
```

Now I want to pass the result of those functions to `doSomething`. I can of course do the following:

```cpp
template<typename F>
void callFunctions(F&& funToCall) {
   doSomething(funToCall());
}
```

But how can I *store* the result of `funToCall` and pass to `doSomething` the correct lvalue or rvalue. I want to do something like:

```cpp
template<typename F>
void callFunctions(F&& funToCall) {
   auto theResult = funToCall();
   doSomething(theResult); // I want to call the correct overload and not always the Foo& one
}
```

Comment: `auto&& theResult`?

Comment: @KamilCuk That avoids an extraneous copy, but currently the code would always pass by lvalue reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
template<typename F>
void callFunctions(F&& funToCall) {
   auto &&theResult = funToCall();
   doSomething(std::forward<decltype(theResult)>(theResult));
}
```

so that `theResult` will correctly deduce to `Foo&` or `Foo&&` as appropriate, and then `std::forward` that type to call the correct overload.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Po9MdP)